# Add 'www' entry to /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, redirection, hosts, hosts-file, hostname

Using Windows and JetBrains IDEA; and trying to serve a hard coded .zip file for scala, since IDEA's plugin is hard-coded to a non-existent location on `scala-lang.org`.

So I've added:

```
127.0.0.1 scala-lang.org
```

And am serving `scala-2.10.0-RC2.zip` (a renamed `scala-2.11.0-M4.zip`) from the following routes:

```
@route('/dist/<filename>')
@route('/downloads/distrib/files/<filename>')
```

Unfortunately it is looking for a `www` prefixed address. How do I make this also redirect locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you, the host www.scala-lang.org needs to resolve to 127.0.0.1 too. That's easy. Just add it to the line in the /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 scala-lang.org www.scala-lang.org